# Fitting Count Data with Poisson & NBD

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, negative-binomial

Assume I have a set of count data that I want to fit with a Poisson/NBD
If I have data of the form:
[image]

then it is rather simple...since we can simply use P(X=x). 
However what would be the approach to fitting data that was of the form:

[image]

i.e. what do I do for the bucket of values in 1-2.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use the chain rule for probability:
$P(A_3,A_2,A_1)=P(A_3|A_2,A_1)*P(A_2|A_1)*P(A_1)$ but not sure how that would be applied in this case.

Comment: Or..if the counts between 1-2 are independent can we simply do:
$P(X=1)+P(X=2)$ i.e. consider something like: people bought hot dogs at the park. They either bought 1 or 2. Since they're independent can we just add?

Comment: You need to show some work before I am willing to help: (a) Please clarify PDF of dist'n with nonstandard abbr. 'Poison/NBD', (b) show your parameter estimate, (c) show your 'rather simple' procedure for the first table. Then it should be possible to give you clues for the next step.

Comment: @BruceET thanks for the reply. 
For Poisson I am using:
$P(X=x)=((\lambda)^xe^{-\lambda})/x!$
For NBD I am using:
if $x = 0 P(x=0)=((\alpha)/(\alpha+1))^r$
following.. I am using recursive for $x>0$ so $P(X=x)=(r+x-1)/(x(\alpha+1))*P(X=x-1)$

I am then calculating log-likelihoods in excel, using solver to maximize the log-likelihood, subject to constraints in my parameters. The actual data I am using is not the data that I put on the question. The data is some 3000+ points.

Comment: My concern is that I have a point in the data where we have something like:
x= 12-17
frequency= 230
Right now what I've done is separately calculated:
P(X=12)
....
P(X=17)
and since they're independent P(X=12-17)=P(X=12)+..+P(X=17) and then maximized LL using that. But I'm not sure this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Usually, counts are merged in order to make _expected_ counts $\ge$ 5. If you don't have access to original data before merging, then your method seems OK. Curious whether you fitting both Pois and 'NBD' or trying to see which one fits best?

Comment: Fitting both and then using chi-square to see which one gives a better fit. Right now it appears as if NBD is the better one. This data set is peculiar. From 1995 study... there is another bucket which is 30+ but there is also this bucker from 12-17..